# What is the best way to securely process authentication checks Cross domain using REST/JSON/PHP/AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, authentication, rest

I am using PHP/CodeIgniter and Tank_Auth library for authentication both on site.com and via the API, and a very basic REST API from Phil Sturgeon.

Right now when a user fills in username/password on Site1. It makes an API call like so:

`http://site2.com/api/index/authenticate?username=jdoe&password=123456`

**On Site2.com:** index/authenticate uses tank_auth library to compare username/password to what is stored in the database.

**My Question:**
Is there a standard to encrypt the password during submission and then decrypt on the other side? Or would an SSL certificate be sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about creating a hash of the 2 with some "salt", pass that in the query string, then make sure it matches by running the same hash on the 2nd server.

```
http://site2.com/api/index/authenticate?username=jdoe&password=123456&cs=fds34wsef3ewtdfgw54ty43wg
```

make sure you keep the salt secret... not too sure about passing this in GET, especially passwords - maybe you could pass a separate id hash instead of the password. Definitely use POST though, and ideally SSL. The more you can obfuscate,encrypt the more secure this will be

Comment: I wouldn't consider POST as more secure. It's rather a cosmetic aspect

Comment: Hmm, I wouldnt place this in GET, how about if he had say google analytics running? unlikely but a possibilty.

Comment: i agree that POST wouldnt be more secure, but it would obfuscate it a bit more.. I think SSL/salted user/pass hash would be fine. Everything i've found on the web is pretty much saying the samething.. The API Call is handled via AJAX so the user never see's the formed URL in question, that is unless they're monitoring XHR requests

Comment: my reason for promoting POST over GET is that GET will potentially get stored in every server / router log that your traffic passes through, POST on the other hand less so

Comment: That is true, but using POST doesn't really conform to REST standards.. since you're receiving data and not submitting data.. but in this case i suppose its worth it.

Comment: Was thinking about this issue a bit.... How about not passing the password or user data like this at all, I assume you are using some sort of session hash approach to deal with login - cookie etc... why not pass the session auth data in a single query sting value, and use that data to set the auth on the 2nd server. Could even go so far as to use something like mCrypt to encrypt / decrypt your data while in transit.. A little overkill possibly but ultimately depends on how secure you wish the link to be.

Comment: I still say if you are passing any data around that might contain personal data un-encrypted - especially passwords, then steer clear of GET